# Python image save error - raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext)) from e ValueError: unknown file extension:

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, os.path

Am just having four weeks of experience in Python. Creating a tool using Tkinter to paste a new company logo on top of the existing images.

The Below method is to, get all images in the given directory and paste the new logo on the initial level. Existing image, edited image, x-position, y-position, a preview of the image and few data's are store in global instance *self.images_all_arr*.

```
def get_img_copy(self):
    self.images_all_arr = []
    existing_img_fldr = self.input_frame.input_frame_data['existing_img_folder']
    for file in os.listdir(existing_img_fldr):
        img_old = Image.open(os.path.join(existing_img_fldr, file))
        img_new_copy = img_old.copy()
        self.pasteImage(img_new_copy, initpaste=True) #process to paste new logo.
        view_new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_new_copy)
        fname, fext = file.split('.')
        formObj = {
            "fname": fname,
            "fext": fext,
            "img_old": img_old,
            "img_new": img_new_copy,
            "img_new_view": view_new_img,
            "add_logo": 1,
            "is_default": 1,
            "is_opacityImg": 0,
            "pos_x": self.defult_x.get(),
            "pos_y": self.defult_y.get()
        }
        self.images_all_arr.append(formObj)
```

After previewing each image in Tkinter screen, doing some adjustment in position x and y(updating pos_x and pos_y in the list *self.images_all_arr*) depends upon the necessity.

Well, once all done. Need to save the edited images. Below method to save images, iterating the list *self.images_all_arr* and call save method as *img['img_new'].save(dir_output)* since *img['img_new']* has updated image.

```
 def generate_imgae(self):
    if len(self.images_all_arr):
        dir_output = 'xxxxx'
        for img in self.images_all_arr:
            print(img['img_new'])
            img['img_new'].save(dir_output)

        print('completed..')
```

But it returns below error,

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2138, in save
> format = EXTENSION[ext]
> KeyError: ''
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Users\662828\WORKSPACE\AAA_python_projects\AMI_automation_poc2\position_and_images.py", line 241, in generate_imgae
> img['img_new'].save(dir_output)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2140, in save
> raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext)) from e
> ValueError: unknown file extension:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dir_output` doesn't contain the file extension, its just `xxxxx`. You need to specify what image file format you want. the error tells us this by saying "unknown file format".

Basically, you either need to include the extension in the file name, or pass it as the next parameter in `image.save`. You can check out the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)

eg.

`image.save('image.png')`

or

`image.save('image', 'png')`

Answer (score 0):

The below code solved my issue. By giving the exact directory, filename and extension of the image as param to the method *image.save()*. Here the result of *opfile* is, *C:\Users\WORKSPACE\AAA_python_projects\test\valid.png*.

```
def generate_imgae(self):
    if len(self.images_all_arr):
        dir_output = r"C:\Users\WORKSPACE\AAA_python_projects\test"
        if not os.path.isdir(dir_output):
            os.mkdir(dir_output)
        for img in self.images_all_arr:
            opfile = os.path.join(dir_output, '{}.{}'.format(img['fname'], img['fext'] ))
            img['img_new'].save(opfile)
        print('completed..')
```

Thanks @dantechguy